# Using dart:web_audio

Tags: dart

I have some confusion debugging some simple app that uses the Web Audio API.

In the developer console I can do something like this:

```
var ctx = new webkitAudioContext(),
osc = ctx.createOscillator();

osc.connect(ctx.destination);
osc.start(0);
```

Trying to get this to work with Dart yields the following errors when I try it like this:

```
AudioContext ctx = new AudioContext();
OscillatorNode osc = ctx.createOscillator();

osc.connect(ctx.destination);
osc.start(0);

//Dart2JS: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<OscillatorNode> has no method 'connect$1' 
//DartVM: Class 'OscillatorNode' has no instance method 'connect' with matching
 arguments. NoSuchMethodError: incorrect number of arguments passed to method 
 named connect' Receiver: Instance of 'OscillatorNode'
```

Stepping through I found that there are two kinds of implementations to the connect method. So I tried to add an extra second param and since I can not really wrap my head around why it needs an int named "output", thinking maybe it is for volume I decided on the value 1 but that yields:

```
//Dart2JS: Uncaught Error: IndexSizeError: DOM Exception 1 flexsynth.html_bootstrap.dart.js:8698 $.main flexsynth.html_bootstrap.dart.js:8698 $$._IsolateContext.eval$1flexsynth.html_bootstrap.dart.js:565 $.startRootIsolate flexsynth.html_bootstrap.dart.js:7181 (anonymous function)

//DartVM: "Dart_IntegerToInt64 expects argument 'integer' to be non-null."
```

Here is where I can't figure out what to do, I think the argument is not null, it is 1.

Googling the errors only leads me to the actual Dart source code.

Is there any place that explains how to work with the dart:web_audio? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the underlying implementation seems to require the parameter `input`, despite it being an optional parameter. This code will work:

```dart
AudioContext ctx = new AudioContext();
OscillatorNode osc = ctx.createOscillator();

osc.connect(ctx.destination, 0, 0);
osc.start(0);
```

This is a known bug, you can star it here: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=6728